# How to send AJAX request when user leaves (closes) the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

### The Situation

Hi,
I'm making a database-driven game, in which there is a question, and a user gains the right to change the question (i.e. write a new question) if they find the correct answer.

But this has an important issue, I think it's called a race condition. The issue is this:

- User 1 finds the answer
- User 1 is prompted to enter a new question
- Before User 1 submits the new question, User 2 finds the new answer too
- Now it's only luck, who is submitting the new question. If User 2 submits the question after User 1, User 2's question overwrites User 1's question.

Right now, I've fixed this issue by using some kind of semaphore, by keeping its `timestamp`. To summarize it works like this:

- User 1 finds the answer
- Semaphore is saved into database like `['user_ip' = 'x.x' , 'time'='y.y' , 'locked'='true']`
- Semaphore expires after t seconds
- New question will be accepted only if semaphore is expired.

so when a new question is submitted, the application accepts it only if the semaphore is **not** locked, and the current time is larger by `t` (15) seconds than the semaphore's date.

But this has a problem too, User 2 is prompted

> "You have found the answer, but somebody found it before you. You can
>   change the question if they don't submit a new question in 15
>   seconds."

So the new winner has to wait 15 seconds, maybe unnecessarily.

Therefore,

### What I Want to Do

I want to prompt the "winner" a form, with a stopwatch (time counter). When it reaches zero, it unlocks the semaphore so that the new winner can submit their question.

But this solution will have this problem:

If the winner closes the page before time counter reaches to zero, then the AJAX request will never be done and the semaphore will be locked indefinitely.

So I have to make sure I have called the `userLeave();` function if the user closes the page.

Google suggests `onbeforeunload` and `onunload` but people also complain about those functions not working. So is there a 100%-sure way to send this AJAX call if a user (a winner) leaves the page ?

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous and therefore non-blocking; the page will not wait for it to finish before being closed.

Comment: As you can imagine, if the page is closed the code is no longer there to run any more code or perform request, and all currect requests are cancelled. The only relyable ways would be either by leaving a connection open and trying to detect when the user disconnects, or performing periodic pings, or a hybrid of both.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that. But forcing the user to wait (like an "are you sure you want to quit?" prompt) or an embedded and hidden swf file, whatever, I want to believe there is a solution for this :)

Comment: Your solution is most likely to use Node.JS. That way you can create your own persistent socket connectoin between the client and the server. If the socket is closed, you can perform whatever is required on the server side that the ajax call would have handled previously

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw this method is not only annoying but also not guaranteed. I believe this message can be disabled, and in any case you wont be able to detect anything if the user simply loses the Internet connection.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I don't know anything about Node.JS but it sounds good.

Comment: Well, you can use SJAX in `onbeforeunload`/`onunload` sucessfully. But you can **never** rely on the clientside logic to send the requests (imagine a browser close/crash that does not fire the event, a browser that does not support the event at all, or a hacker attacking your server by creating many never-resolved semaphores…). If you want to do a timed countdown solution, you have to implement the timer on the server side.

Comment: @Bergi and Havenard, you are right about the internet crash case. But from what I understand, Node.JS can handle all these situations, right? For the hacker case, I think they would need a brute-force method, and if it becomes a problem, I can make a captcha or limit the max.requests per time, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a 100%-sure way to send this AJAX call if a user (a winner) leaves the page?

You can ***never*** rely on the client doing anything 100%. Think of network connectivity losses, browser crashes, not available features (from HTML5-incompatible browsers to disabled javascript), scripting errors, misconfigured agents that do call (or not) your API in unexpected ways or hackers doing the same on purpose…

The only thing you can expect of a client is that he does nothing - which is called a timeout.

If you want your semaphore to expire at a certain time, you have to create the timer serverside. If you want, you can additionally abort the timer and expire immediatley when a client signals that he's not going to submit an answer (by whichever means). If you want to try to catch closing the page, you can use synchronous (A)JAX from an `unload` event.

Btw: While I don't know your game, it would be easier and probably more comfortable if you simply would accept both new questions :-)

Comment: hehe:) but the game itself is "one question, the knower changes it", so that is not an option. You are right, the best option with a free host is to handle the timing in server-side. Thanks !