# How to update user list while a user entering/leaving a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a chat application in which i want to detect and fire ajax when a user leaving a page by clicking back button or some other link or by closing the browser.

[image]

So please give your valuable solution how to achieve this.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send AJAX request when user leaves (closes) the page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839771/how-to-send-ajax-request-when-user-leaves-closes-the-page)

Comment: Hi  i want   the reason for negative feedback.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do that. The event `window.onbeforeunload` fires when the user is leaving the page, but it won't allow you to do any ajax calls.

All you can do is return a string, which will be shown to the user as a `confirm` dialog. If user presses <kbd>Cancel</kbd>, he will remain in the page, else the page will be unloaded.

```
return  "Are you sure, you want to leave this page?" // this is all you can do
```

Comment: Ya, AFAIK, there is no reliable method to do that in a cross browser way, btw not mentioning user could turn off computer power

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
       $('body').mousemove(function() {
          $('body').unbind("mousemove");
               ajaxCall();
           });
        return "Are you sure? All work will lost! Cancel to upload the work";
};
```

Comment: What is the purpose of binding mousemove event?

Comment: In my code the purpose is to wait for the client decision.
if the decision is to stay - call some ajax function.
else do nothing and close the page.

Comment: In practice this will not work properly, as the Ajax call will not stop the browser stopping execution and closing the window, because it is meant to be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind on [Window.onunload()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp) event, or [jquery unload](https://api.jquery.com/unload/) if you using Jquery.
Also more widely answered in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274486/doing-an-ajax-call-on-window-unload)